# Can std::function and inheritance coexist?

Tags: c++, c++17

I have one file with abstract class

```
struct Abstract {
    virtual bool preflightCheck(void) = 0;
    std::function<void(Abstract *)> didIssueError;
    virtual ~Abstract() {}
}
```

One file with derived class

```
class Derived : public Abstract {
    bool preflightCheck(void) {
        if(didIssueError != nullptr)
            this->didIssueError(reinterpret_cast<MediaAssetAbstract*>(this));
    }
}
```

And then I have file where I call `didIssueError` as lambda

```
bool testDerived(Abstract & derived) {
    derived.preflightCheck();
    derived.didIssueError = [&derived](Abstract * derived) {
        std::cout << "error" << std::endl;
    };
    return true;
}

int main() {
    auto derived = Derived();
    assert(testDerived(derived));
    return 0;
}
```

If I remove the check on `nullptr`, the program will crash with message 
 `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_function_call' what():  bad_function_call`.

Where could be problem, please? With the inaccesibility from derived class to the `didIssueError`?

Comment: You try to call `didIssueError` *before* you assign anything to it. What did you expect that to do besides throwing a `std::bad_function_call`?

Comment: You're calling `preflightCheck` *before* assigning a valid callable into `didIssueError`. Additionally, what's with the savage `reinterpret_cast`?

Comment: ... and what is the relationship between `Abstract` and `MediaAssetAbstract`? Forgotten rename?

Comment: your reinterpret cast is surely wrong. You must only use it if you really really know what you're doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can `std::function` and inheritance coexist?

Sure.

> If I remove the check on `nullptr`, the program will crash with message 
>    `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_function_call' what():  bad_function_call`.
>
> Where could be problem, please?

The problem is that you call `didIssueError` before you assign a function to it:

> ```
> // call:
> derived.preflightCheck();
>
> // assignment:
> derived.didIssueError = [&derived](Abstract * derived) {
>     std::cout << "error" << std::endl;
> };
> ```

C++ is a procedural, not a data-flow language.

---

P.S. This:

> ```
> this->didIssueError(reinterpret_cast<MediaAssetAbstract*>(this));
> ```

is wrong.